# Holding Vars for long time in ASP/MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET-MVC-application I store information in static classes with static vars. But ASP.NET is recycling all data and threads after and my "App_Start"-procedure will call after the cleanup.

I solved the problem with the backup-tasks with HangFire.
But to generate the static-class, I need a long time. The first request after the recycle has to wait while the static-classes are set up.

Why the delay? I am using the EntityFramework and for correct handling I need all records from the database with their relations.
So I hold all records with static-classes and use the database as 2nd strategy.

I have no ideas what I can do to improve performance.
My first idea was to serialize the complete data - but how is the performance for deserialize a ArrayList with 2K or more records?
Is there a way to prevent the recyclefor my static ArrayList?

Comment: 2000 records should not take a long time to read from a database.  Also, can you explain why you need to keep all the data in memory at all times?  This sounds like an anti-pattern but maybe there is some reasoning behind this.

Comment: Is your app pool set to AlwaysRunning?

Comment: I have many relations (lazy loading need very long) and my records are hierarchic I need to rebuild the hierarchy.
Yeah, app is set to "AlwaysRunning", but the clean-up clear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you use the [application cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx) mechanism for ASP.NET instead. However, by default, the cache is still in-memory and maintained within the process, so app pool recycles would still wipe it out. The solution is to change the storage location of the application cache so it's in a different process. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3287014/119549) for some recommendations for how to store your application cache.

In short, I wouldn't recommend trying to avoid app pool recycling since it can really save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look tomorrow.